# Match value where string does not contain a certain word

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a word in a string only if a certain word occurs within the first 10 characters of the string.
This is my approach:

```
import re

string_array = ["foo bar\nbaz qux", "baz qux foo bar", "baz qux"]
for string in string_array:
    a = re.search("(?s)^(?!.{0,10}bar).*(qux).*$", string)
    print(a)
```

I tried this in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/d9sntE/1) but this would still match the entire string even when it contains `bar`. I also tried with a negative lookbehind but then the first part would be required to be a fixed length which in my case cannot. What am I doing wrong?
I'd expect to get a match in all except for the first string

Comment: Your regex will check that bar should not be present using negative lookahead, try with positive lookahead

Answer (score 0):

The `(?!.{0,10}bar)` is preventing the regex engine from matching any string that has `bar` within the first 10 characters. So, the regex engine will only start matching at the 11th character.

Try using this code below:

```
import re

string_array = ["foo bar\nbaz qux", "baz qux foo bar", "baz qux"]
for string in string_array:
    a = re.search("^(?=.{0,10}bar).*?(qux)", string, re.DOTALL)
    print(a)
```

Comment: This would not match any of the strings in my list. I want to create a negation of the positive lookahead. So only if "bar" is found within the first 10 characters, the string should not return a match

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a complex *regex only* solution, you can just look for every **bar** occurrence and check it's position using `match.start()` and `match.end()`

```
import re

arrayIndex = 0    
count = 0

string_array = ["foo bar\nbaz qux", "baz qux foo bar", "baz qux"]
for string in string_array:
    for match in re.finditer(r'bar', string):
        count += 1
        print("array index", arrayIndex, "match", count, match.group(), "start index", match.start(), "End index", match.end())
    arrayIndex += 1
```

Check the solution's fiddle [here](https://trinket.io/python3/1ead9a74de)